# Use a TypeScript defined type's keys as a property type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Sorry for the confusing title. Here's my issue.

I have a type:

```
type Person = {
    firstName?: string;
    middleName?: string;
    lastName?: string;
}
```

Let's say I want to get one of these attributes dynamically.

```
const getPersonAttribute = (field: string) => {
    return person[field];
}
```

This throws TS errors (something about implicit type `<string>` or `<any>` cannot be an index of type `Person`), so to get it to work, I'm doing this:

```
const getPersonAttribute = (field: 'firstName' | 'middleName' | 'lastName') => {
    return person[field];
}
```

Is there a better way to do this? Somehow dynamically getting the Type's properties?

Comment: like `keyof Person`?

Comment: Yep. Exactly like that. As noted in the other answers, it looks like for mixed types it's a little different. getPersonAttribute<K extends keyof Person>(field: K) {}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just want `keyof`, as documented [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types):

```
declare const person: Person;
const getPersonAttribute = (field: keyof Person) => {
  return person[field]; // okay
}
// const getPersonAttribute: (field: keyof Person) => string | undefined
```

In this case the return type of `getPersonAttribute` is `string | undefined`.  If you had different types of properties in `Person` (say, an `age` of type `number`),

```
type Person = {
  firstName?: string;
  middleName?: string;
  lastName?: string;
  age?: number;
}
```

then the return type would be the union of `string`, `number`, and `undefined`, which might not be specific enough for your use cases:

```
// const getPersonAttribute: (field: keyof Person) => string | number | undefined
const personLastName = getPersonAttribute("lastName"); // string | number | undefined
const personAge = getPersonAttribute("age"); // string | number | undefined
```

If you want `getPersonAttribute()`'s output type to depend on the *particular* input key, then you need to make the function [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) in the input key type:

```
const getPersonAttributeGen = <K extends keyof Person>(field: K) => {
  return person[field]; // okay
}
// const getPersonAttributeGen: 
// <K extends "firstName" | "middleName" | "lastName" | "age">(field: K) => Person[K]
```

This produces the output of type `Person[K]`, a lookup type (documented in the same link above):

```
const personLastNameBetter = getPersonAttributeGen("lastName"); // string | undefined
const personAgeBetter = getPersonAttributeGen("age"); // number | undefined
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAChBOBnA9gOygXigbwFBSgDMBLJYAOQEMBbCAfgC4pFh5jUBzAbnymuIAmAgDYQqtRs1btuvYZRbj6TFm05covSh2VRUAV2oAjBDwC+uXAIgBjefGg20LKJCRomcd6h5PULnWAvFFQAQWBpI31gaCwAChIIYQEmAGsIEGRCWAQQgEpMAD4cXgdgfXh0NxCAbUTkgF0NAHpmqGRUyhBcC1aoPwCIINy0cMjoiCYE4iSUqHTM7OC0Aoxi1RkoAB89QxN4bah9VGsSVAgBSwHgVxHUABkFChpYqEDlsIi2KJi4gCJ5IoXn88i02htOIcDMYEIdjqd2BdcNdbt5QjpMG8hh8xt8Jv9tBAQWCpGoOFC9rCdvCIGckcjnDd3ndccQfhAAOIQdBYAA8AGkoBAAB4xE6IeYZLI5byFaazJj81bFPAEMoVKp3OozRokjpdHq4Poo5lor5siZc1BMI1tAVC0XcgQSv4kMhKP6HP78ISiD1ewHPWienZ-Ql-OX1OZKooy2r8hpXRmokKPIG0ABCQxiBywppCrPZVv+gY9oKgfQh5OpJ1piMuKOqox0WYisLz2JZ5qL3IJOmJFba0P2cNrdIEQA)

Comment: Perfect. Thank you! The extra detail and explanation is much appreciated!

Comment: But why is Typescript working this way? I can't see the difference between these two or how in the latter implementation, we're giving more _clues_ to typescript. is it just how Typescript chose to work or there's a good reason behind it?

Comment: "I can't see the difference between these two" They are annotated differently. `keyof Person` is a union type.  If `field` is of type `keyof Person`, then `person[field]` is of type `Person[keyof Person]`, another union type.  Union in, union out.  If you want something more specific than that, you annotate as a generic.  `<K extends keyof Person>` with `field` of type `K` means `K` is potentially *narrower* than `keyof Person`, and then `person[field]` is of type `Person[K]`, which is potentially narrower than `Person[keyof Person]`, depending what `K` is inferred to be when you call the fn.

Comment: "Is it just how TypeScript chose to work or there's a good reason behind it?"  I'm not sure what you're asking here; do you think that if I just write `field => person[field]` the compiler should infer the generic signature?  That's interesting and has been suggested (I think [this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17428) does) but there's no clear way to do it without bogging down the compiler.  You could ask the same thing for conditional types (another feature) but, as mentioned in [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912), it's a bad idea:

Comment: You generally *don't* want every detail of a function implementation reflected in its call signature. Call signatures are contracts, and the implementation details are hidden intentionally.  If I say `const greet = (x: string) => "Hello, "+x+"!"` I probably want the compiler to say that's a function from `string` to `string`, and not that it specifically prepends `"Hello"` to a string.  If I decide to change `"Hello"` to `"Greetings"`, that's an implementation detail, not a function signature change.  If I *do* want something more specific that's expressible in the type system, I can annotate.

Answer (score 1):

With `keyof` you can get the keys of a certain type. Here's the syntaxis I would use (notice I went for a function instead of arrow function to make it more readable):

```
function getPersonAttribute<K extends keyof Person>(field: K) {
    return person[field];
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I only marked the other answer as the accepted answer because the guy went into great detail. But this is what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: I understand! Happy to help anyway :)